# Get only particular properties of objects array using standart AngularJS filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter, angular-filters

I have an array of objects:

```
[{
    "name": "Shop #1",
    "cost": "100",
    "currency": "RUB"
}, {
    "name": "Shop #2",
    "cost": "99",
    "currency": "EUR"
}, {
    "name": "Shop #3",
    "cost": "2",
    "currency": "USD"
}]
```

Want to get filtered result (show only "cost" and "currency" properties):

```
[{
    "cost": "100",
    "currency": "RUB"
}, {
    "cost": "99",
    "currency": "EUR"
}, {
    "cost": "2",
    "currency": "USD"
}]
```

Is it possible **to do that with standart AngularJS [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) component**?

Here is an example fiddle for convenience : https://jsfiddle.net/serikov/qa706tu3/

P.S. I know [how to do that](https://jsfiddle.net/serikov/qa706tu3/) via [custom filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09), but need solution using standart filter component.

Comment: Wouldn't an `if` work?

Comment: If you can use it in controller then you can use ES5 map.

Comment: you can't really do this with the standard filter. it only filters out elements from an array, it does not filter out properties of elements. Also this doesn't look like a problem you'd solve with a filter anyway.. the best way to do it would be to just not show those properties on screen, like hiding a column in a table.